# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, sql

> `#1452` - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`schoolzone`., CONSTRAINT `#sql-10e0_7f2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`teacherid`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`teacherid`))

Comment: You need to provide more details on your issue.  Just posting an error message with no code is not helpful.  But typically this means that you are violating a foreign key by not having a row in the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the error is because you are inserting a record on table `schoolZone` with value of the column `teacherid` that doesn't exist on table `teacher`. Remember that the table you are inserting the record is dependent on table `teacher`.

Below is an example that shows how you get the error.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2237b/2)

Comment: I have table teacher and column teacher id.For another table it worked but only for this table it s not getting altered

Comment: can you post what are the `ID` for the teacher table? and what record are you trying to insert on the other table?